# What is the most efficient way to get the relationship method names on a Laravel Eloquent object?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

A lot of time, I've had reasons to get the names of the relationships defined on an Eloquent object. Since Laravel currently provides no way/helper to do this, I came up with the below:

```
public static function getRelationshipsForEloquentlModel($eloquentObject) {
    $methods   = self::getDirectClassMethods($eloquentObject);
    $relations = [];

    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        try {
                $reflection = new \ReflectionMethod($eloquentObject, $method);

                //filter out non-eloquent relationship methods that expect parameters in
                //their signature (else they blow up when they get called below without pars)
                $pars = $reflection->getNumberOfParameters();

                if ($pars == 0) {
                    $possibleRelationship = $eloquentObject->$method();

                    //one of the things we can use to distinctively identify an eloquent
                    //relationship method (BelongsTo, HasMany...etc) is to check for
                    //one of the public methods defined in Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php
                    //(and hope that it is not discontinued/removed in future versions of Laravel :))
                    if (method_exists($possibleRelationship, "getEager")) {
                        $relationshipType = get_class($possibleRelationship);

                        //remove namespace
                        if ($pos = strrpos($relationshipType, '\\')) {
                            $relationshipType = substr($relationshipType, $pos + 1);
                        }

                        $relations[$method] = $relationshipType;
                    }
                }
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                //Eloquent's save() method will throw some
                //sql error because $eloquentObject may be
                //an empty object like new App\User (so some NOT NULL db fields may blow up)
            }
        }

        return $relations;
    }
```

And the helper class `getDirectClassMethods` is below (courtesy of [onesimus on official PHP docs comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php#43379)):

```
public static function getDirectClassMethods($class) {
        $array1 = get_class_methods($class);
        if ($parent_class = get_parent_class($class)) {
            $array2 = get_class_methods($parent_class);
            $array3 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
        } else {
            $array3 = $array1;
        }
        return ($array3);
    }
```

Now this whole code listing looks so cumbersome and verbose to me, at least when the desired task is such a simple one. Is there a better/faster/more efficient way of achieving this without all these verbosity?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the name of the relation? Do you want the name of the foreign key in the database?

Comment: No, I want a dynamic way to get the relationship methods defined on a given eloquent object, just as in the code above, but to do so efficiently/faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This trait should help

```
    namespace App;

    use ErrorException;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
    use ReflectionClass;
    use ReflectionMethod;

    trait RelationshipsTrait
    {
        public function relationships() {

            $model = new static;

            $relationships = [];

            foreach((new ReflectionClass($model))->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method)
            {
                if ($method->class != get_class($model) ||
                    !empty($method->getParameters()) ||
                    $method->getName() == __FUNCTION__) {
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    $return = $method->invoke($model);

                    if ($return instanceof Relation) {
                        $relationships[$method->getName()] = [
                            'type' => (new ReflectionClass($return))->getShortName(),
                            'model' => (new ReflectionClass($return->getRelated()))->getName()
                        ];
                    }
                } catch(ErrorException $e) {}
            }

            return $relationships;
        }
    }
```

You should get an array of arrays, just add the trait to any models.

```
    class Article extends Model
    {
        use RelationshipsTrait;

        ...
    }

    $article = new Article;
    dd($article->relationships());
```

Should output

```
    "example" => array:2 [▼
        "type" => "BelongsTo"
        "model" => "App\Example"
      ],
      "gallery" => array:2 [▼
        "type" => "MorphMany"
        "model" => "App\Gallery"
      ]
```

Comment: Whao! This is super cool! However, I am not so comfy with the idea of having to use trait on the target Eloquent class (it doesn't feel outta-the-box solution), hence I am not marking as right answer yet (at least not for now). But your approach is more elegant. Let's see what others think of this/come-up with